# PHP WooCommerce Rest API Client Library Create Multiple Coupons

Tags: php, arrays, woocommerce

I am trying to create multiple coupons in my WordPress site externally from my PHP site and I am making a use of woocommerce-api client library.
I am preparing an array of coupon codes to pass to the Create Coupon method so that I can create multiple coupons at once. but its not really working as it returns me the following Error message " Error: Missing parameter code [woocommerce_api_missing_coupon_code]" Here is my Code

```
      foreach ($tags->result() as $row) {
            $coupons[$i]['code'] = $row->id_tag;
            $coupons[$i]['type'] = 'fixed_cart';
            $coupons[$i]['amount'] = 5;
            $i++;
        }

        print_r($coupons);
        print_r($coupons[0]);
        require_once '/application/lib/woocommerce-api.php';
        $consumer_key = 'ck_consumerKey'; // Add your own Consumer Key here
        $consumer_secret = 'cs_ConsumeSecret'; // Add your own Consumer Secret here
        $store_url = 'http://mySiteUrl'; // Add the home URL to the store you want to connect to here             
        try
        {
           $client = new WC_API_Client( $store_url, $consumer_key, $consumer_secret );

           $client->coupons->create( $coupons[0]);
           $client->coupons->create( $coupons);
        }
        catch ( WC_API_Client_Exception $e ) 
        {
            echo $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
            echo $e->getCode() . PHP_EOL;
            if ( $e instanceof WC_API_Client_HTTP_Exception ) 
            {
                print_r( $e->get_request() );
                print_r( $e->get_response() );
            }

        }
```

This $client->coupons->create( $coupons[0]) where I am passing only the first index of array creates a single coupon successfully but the second line where I pass the whole array to the create method doesn't create any coupon and returns me the following error 
 Error: Missing parameter code[woocommerce_api_missing_coupon_code]

I have printed the coupons[] array and it contains the following data

```
 Array ( [0] => Array ( [code] => AA12B001 [type] => fixed_cart [amount] => 5 ) [1] => Array ( [code] => AA12B002 [type] => fixed_cart [amount] => 5 ))
```

where as if i print the coupons[0] it contains the following data

```
 Array ( [code] => AA12B001 [type] => fixed_cart [amount] => 5 )
```

Any Help Please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why passing the entire array of coupons doesn't work is because the REST client library doesn't define the `coupons/bulk` endpoint.

The easier approach is to modify the code you are using, tweak your code as follows

```
require_once '/application/lib/woocommerce-api.php';
$consumer_key = 'ck_consumerKey'; // Add your own Consumer Key here
$consumer_secret = 'cs_ConsumeSecret'; // Add your own Consumer Secret here
$store_url = 'http://mySiteUrl'; // Add the home URL to the store you want to connect to here             

try
{
   $client = new WC_API_Client( $store_url, $consumer_key, $consumer_secret );

   foreach ($tags->result() as $row) {
        $coupons = array();
        $coupons['code'] = $row->id_tag;
        $coupons['type'] = 'fixed_cart';
        $coupons['amount'] = 5;
        $client->coupons->create( $coupons);
    }

     .... //continue with the rest of the code
```

Another approach would be to modify the REST client library, but this is going to be a time consuming process. Technically, whether you loop in the client code and create a coupon at a time, or you hand over the entire coupons array to WooCommerce and let WooCommerce create coupons by looping will have the same effect.

The only difference is efficiency, the first approach of creating a coupon a time is less efficient, however unless you have thousands of coupons to create, it shouldn't matter.

**EDIT**

Here's the solution

1.Edit `lib/woocommerce-api/resources/class-wc-api-client-coupons.php` and add the following code to it

```
public function create_bulk( $data ) {

    $this->object_namespace = 'coupons';

    $this->set_request_args( array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'body'   => $data,
        'path'   => 'bulk',
    ) );

    return $this->do_request();
}
```

2.Now make a call to `$client->coupons->create_bulk( $coupons );`

I have tested this locally and it works.

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned, WooCommerce REST API does define a `bulk` endpoint, its the Kloon client library that doesn't make use of that endpoint.

Comment: Thanks for your help , I already have tried this approach but my problem is that i need to create more than 20000 coupons at once, can you please suggest me the best approach to solve the issue? In the WooCommerce Rest API Docs they have mentioned to create multiple coupons at once by sending the cURL commands, but as you say "REST client library doesn't define the coupons/bulk endpoint" Is there a way that i could send the cURL command from my php code to get over this problem?

Comment: Another approach would be to generate a CSV containing the 20000 coupons and then import it using code on the server.

Comment: as you have mentioned that unless i have to create thousands of coupons, it shouldn't matter, but in my case its taking lots of time even creating 100 coupons, like more than 80 seconds or so , and creating 200 coupons at once crashes in the middle.

Comment: is there a way that i can directly make a use of WC Rest API and send it the command from my PHP code to create the coupons?

Comment: I have updated my answer with the solution. I have tested it locally and it works.

Comment: Thank you very much but its producing the following error on my side "Error: No route was found matching the URL and request method [woocommerce_api_no_route] "

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91582/discussion-between-anand-shah-and-umer).

Comment: When I am shift MAMP to live linux server this is not working

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved my problem by following the steps below.

1: Updated my Woo Commerce version from 2.3.10 to 2.4.7 because the REST API in below versions doesn't facilitate bulk operations mode.

2: After update I need to make minor changes into "class-wc-api-coupons.php" This is the updated WC REST API class which offers a bulk method to create multiple coupons but there is a restriction of MAX 100 bulk operation inside the method,I increased the limit to 2000.(I could find this api class under installed plugins/woocommerce/includes/api).

3:Finally I followed the instruction by @Anand e.g WC client API doesn't support bulk end point so we need to modify/extend the client API, so I added the following function into my "class-wc-api-client-resource-coupons" class

```
public function create_bulk( $data ) {

$this->object_namespace = 'coupons';

$this->set_request_args( array(
    'method' => 'POST',
    'body'   => $data,
    'path'   => 'bulk',
) );

return $this->do_request();
}
```

Now I can make call to this function anywhere in my client code and pass an array of coupon codes to create hundreds of coupons in bulk.

Thanks to @Anand for many help.